# Population of the coefficient matrix of a linear system Ax=b stemming from the finite differences of an arbitrary geometry

Tags: finite-difference, linear-solver, computational-geometry

I've been looking into solving a linear system $$Ax=b$$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}$ is the sparse coefficient matrix of size $K\times K$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$ is the right-hand side (i.e., the source term) of size $K\times 1$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is the vector of unknowns (also of size $K\times 1$). The system of equations is obtained by discretizing the 2D Poisson partial differential equation by means of the central finite differences method. The domain over which the 2D Poisson equation is calculated is in general an arbitrary geometry. As an example, consider the geometry illustrated in the figure below:

[image]

where the pink color indicates the relevant domain where the Poisson equation needs to be solved, while the blue color is the region in which the Poisson equation does not need to be solved (red lines indicate locations of Dirichlet boundaries, and green lines are positions of Neumann boundaries).

What I typically do is I represent the figure with a data structure, $L$ that has value of $1$ at the simulation region, value of $0$ outside the simulation region, $-1$ at the Dirichlet boundary, and $-2$ at the Neumann boundary. The indices $(i,j)$ used to discretize the 2D geometry are then replaced by the index $k=j+Mi$ so that 2D quantities can be represented via 1D vectors.

Since for the second-order central finite differences the matrix $A$ ends up being penta-diagonal, one can solve the linear system without forming an actual matrix $A$ and instead one can work with coefficient formulas, as they are fairly simple to derive and manipulate. Another advantage of this non-matrix-based approach is that one can use data structure $L$ and check if the current point is in or out of the simulation region ($L_{i,j}==1$ or $L_{i,j}<1$). In this way, the out-of-bounds simulation region (blue regions in the figure above) can be omitted from the numerical calculations.

However, my question is if I was to form the actual sparse matrix structure via, e.g., Eigen library (or any other library that provides the sparse matrices), how would I populate it optimally? Especially, how would I deal with points in the blue region? Note that every blue point would result in an all-zeros row in the matrix $A$ if included in it. If I were to skip the blue points, should I then consider a reduced system of equations, $\tilde{A}\tilde{x}=\tilde{b}$, where quantities with tilde include only pink points (and possibly boundary regions)?

I would appreciate any insight into this problem.

Comment: You can use a reduced system but it will ruin the pentadiagonal matrix structure. If you use a non-reduced version then you can use a sparse matrix with just 5 diagonal vectors as to not store a column and row index vectors. I have no idea why you would want to turn a matrix-free problem into one requiring the storage and access of a sparse matrix though. On another note - Neumann conditions in 2D are typically $\partial_n u = h$ where $n$ is the normal to the boundary, so make sure that's properly discretised.

Comment: @lightxbulb, thanks for the comment. 
You are right - if given a solver where I can directly manipulate coefficients then I don't need an actual matrix. However, I was looking into Eigen solvers, (GMRES & BiCGstab), which require sparse matrix as an input. Typically I construct this matrix by only populating it with $k$ indices of non-zero elements, but the final sparse matrix is still 'aware' of the zero-row entries. E.g., if I tell it to store data in 7th, 8th and 9th row, but then to skip 10th, and store further in 11th, 12th, etc., I worry that this complicates the solution procedure.

Comment: BiCGStab needs only matrix-vector multiplication as a routine. If eigen doesn't have it you can easily implement it. I am guessing GMRES should also be able to be implemented like that.

Comment: I found this: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__MatrixfreeSolverExample.html